# Grafana dashboard Variables: how to extract a label value when the metric equal to a value

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I have a metric to monitor the health status of microservices called `nodejs_microservice_health_status`.

I want to create a variable `failedmicroservice` which extracts the value of the `service` label of the metrics when `nodejs_microservice_health_status` equals to 0.

The PromQL query `nodejs_microservice_health_status == bool 0` returns all the items equals to 0, but when I tried to set the Query of the variable to `label_values({nodejs_microservice_health_status == bool 0}, service)`,
[image]

I got the following error:

[image]

Do anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following values,

Query:

```
query_result(nodejs_microservice_health_status==0)
```

Regex:

```
/.*service=\"([^\"]+)\".*/
```